# Why does interp1d in scipy give a NaN when the first 2 values of the x-array are identical? (fill_value = 0)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.array([ 0,  0,   0,  0,   0,  30])
time = np.array([ 5,  5,  10,  10,  10,  20])

intx = interp1d(time,x,'linear', 0, True, False, 0)
print intx([4,5,5,6,10,11,20, 20.0001])

>>> [  0.  nan  nan   0.   0.   3.  30.   0.]
```

As you can see, in all cases except where the time value == the first pair of values, the interpolant returns a real number.

I am aware of numpy.unique(), this is just an academic question. This is Anaconda Python 2.7 running in iPython.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to interpolate points that are outside the interval, this causes that `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` launches a `RuntimeWarning` when it tries to calculate the slope between two points (it happens in interpolate.py around line 416):

```
slope = (y_hi - y_lo) / (x_hi - x_lo)[:, None]
```

See what happens when you move your points within the interval:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> x = np.array([ 5,  5,  10,  10,  10,  20])
>>> y = np.array([ 0,  0,   0,  0,   0,  30])
>>> X = np.array([5.1,5.1,5.1,6,10,11,20, 19.999])
>>> f = interp1d(x,y,'linear', 0, True, False, 0)
>>> Y = f(X)
 [  0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      3.     30.     29.997]
```

If you plot it you could see that all makes sense:

[image]

This is how `interp1d` works:

1. You pass `x` and `y`to `interp1d` and it creates a `f` callable method
2. Then you pass the new `x_new` values in which you want to evaluate `f` and it performs the following steps:

   - Find where in the original data, the values to interpolate would be inserted.

     ```
     >>> x_new_indices = np.searchsorted(x, X)
     ```
   - Clip x_new_indices so that they are within the range of `x` indices and at least 1.  Removes mis-interpolation of `x_new[n] = x[0]`

     ```
     >>> x_new_indices = x_new_indices.clip(1, len(x)-1).astype(int)
     ```
   - Calculate the slope of regions that each `x_new` value falls in.

     ```
     >>> lo = x_new_indices - 1
     >>> hi = x_new_indices
     >>> x_lo = x[lo]
     >>> x_hi = x[hi]
     >>> y_lo = y[lo]
     >>> y_hi = y[hi]
     ```
   - Calculate the actual value for each entry in `x_new`.

     ```
     >>> slope = (y_hi - y_lo) / (x_hi - x_lo)[:, None]
     >>> y_new = slope*(x_new - x_lo)[:, None] + y_lo
     ```

Comment: Great answer! Let me make sure I understand it. So, when I put in 5 as `x_new` (we'll refer to it as five), interp1d sorts five into my array so that `[5 5 10 10 10 20]` becomes `[five 5 5 10 10 10 20]`. My assumption is that for trivial reasons new duplicates are always put to the left of existing identical entries. Then the process you mentioned, which makes sure the index is at least 1 rearranges the array to become `[5 five 5 10 10 10 20]`. The slope is therefore `NaN` because `x_lo` = 5 and `x_hi` = 5. Finally, `y_new = NaN*0` = `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

In the above case, I'd suggest just sample points for the Y variable. Eg. consider the following points.

```
x= [275, 275]
y= [120, 120]
```

the above points represent a line parallel to the Y-axis. Therefore, the slope of the line is undefined. So, here you can sample points just for the Y variable and replicate value of the X variable for each of them. You will find the below plots intuitive.
**Plot 1 -**
[image: Two initial points]

**Plot 2 -**
[image: Sample only y points keeping x same!]